# VS 2010 XAML Control Footer Tags

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml

When I add a control from the toolbox (either double-clicking or dragging), it automatically uses the self closing form of the control, like so:

```
<StackPanel />
```

This is completely useless for panels of any type. Is there any way to change to behavior to always use an explicit closing tag, like so:

```
<StackPanel></StackPanel>
```

If I must deal with all items using an explicit closing tag, that's fine. I just don't want to have to essentially rewrite the tag every time, making the toolbox useless.

Also, I do use Resharper 7, so if there's a way to do this with Resharper, that is welcome as well.

Comment: This is a personal taste issue, but the ToolBox is a useless tool for me. With ReSharper, it's enough to enter `<SP` (capitalized) and it will show you `StackPanel` in intellisense. Also, it's a learning algorithm - after several times that you enter `<SP` and select `StackPanel`, entering `<SP` will pre-select `StackPanel` from the list (even if it's not the first item). Then the flow is: Enter `<SP`, <ArrowDown>, <Enter>. It's extremely fast. One of the most useful features of ReSharper for XAML.

Comment: There are times when I'm moving around with the mouse, and I need to add several items at the same time to the Window. If I already have my  hand on the mouse, it's quicker to double click the StackPanel, click inside the tags, then double click all the other controls that go in it. It may seem like blasphemy, but I don't like ReSharper's Intellisense and I don't use it. Learning algorithms also make me sad - I use three statusbars in a row, learn that it needs "stat", then when I want a stackpanel, I type "sta" because that's been stackpanel the last 3 times, and I am betrayed.

Comment: As I said, it depends on your personal taste. The trick with ReSharper is to use only capital letters - it's quite amazing how only three letters are enough (usually) to get to the right item. In your case, I'd remember `SP` and `SB` not `sta`. Not trying to convince or anything, it took me about two weeks of conscious learning to use capitals (including deleting the tag and re-writing it with capitals), but once I got used to it - you wouldn't be able to pry ReSharper out of my dying fingers. :) It's definitely worth a try.

Comment: I'll give it some thought. Refusing to learn new methods is a quick way to fall behind as a programmer. In any case, there are still times at which it is quicker to use the mouse to add the controls en masse, rather than type them in, so the question is still valid.